# Zend Framework: Enable jQuery in single view

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework

Currently working with ZF and ZendX_JQuery.

As I understand, script links to Google's CDN JQuery are only included in the `<head>` section of a view if ZF JQuery is referenced in some way in the MVC.

However, I'm working with 'Cloud Zoom', a JQuery library for image zooming.

The view I wish to include Cloud Zoom in has no reference to JQuery, and therefore the script links are not included in the head. How can I make ZF include the script links in the head section of the page without explicitly including any ZF JQuery references in the MVC?

Comment: Not sure this is what you want, but you can manipulate head section using [HeadScript view helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.headscript) from your views.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense, you are working in the MVC (as i take it) and you want to use jQuery, but you don't want to reference it within the MVC? You can enable and disable zendx jquery with the view helper. That way you can have the code in your layout but only reference it on the few occasional views that require it.

Comment: Hi all,
Thanks for the replies.
I have zendx jquery enabled with the view helper.
However, the links to the jQuery script file (hosted on Google's CDN) are only placed in the view output when a zendx jquery element is referred to in the view (e.g. through ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element_DatePicker). I'd like to know if there's a way to insert the jQuery script links without need to reference a zendx jquery element. I suppose the last resort would be to manually insert the script links using Marcin's headscript view helper suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zendx.jquery.view.html

> To access the javascript we have to
>   utilize the jQuery() functionality.
>   Both helpers already activated their
>   dependencies that is they have called
>   jQuery()->enable() and
>   jQuery()->uiEnable()

i have this code in my layout

```
if ($this->jQuery()->isEnabled()) {
    $this->headScript()->appendFile('/scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker-it.js');//localizazione di DatePicker
    echo $this->jQuery()->setRenderMode(ZendX_JQuery::RENDER_JAVASCRIPT | ZendX_JQuery::RENDER_JQUERY_ON_LOAD);
}
```

so i guess you have to do something like `$this->jQuery()->enable()->enableui()`